# Вывод пользователей в MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Как реализовать вывод списка всех зарегистрированных пользователей, а также возможность удалять, редактировать и добавлять новых?

Вывод пользователей нужно реализовать через UserManager.
Сейчас HomeController выглядит следующим образом:

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public HomeController()
{
}

public HomeController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}

public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _signInManager = value;
    }
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var us = UserManager.Users.ToList();
    return View(us);
}
```

Какой следующий шаг?

Comment: а в чем вопрос заключается? ваш код не работает?

Comment: Какой следующий шаг? Необходимо ведь создать представление, как я понимаю
И как реализовать редактирование/удаление

Comment: я думаю стоит добавить эти вопросы в пост